# Uploading images to sub folders

Tags: channel-entries

Is it possible to upload images to subfolders? Client wants to organize each entries images. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as different upload locations. Content -> Files -> File Upload Preferences menu (EE2). Alternatively defined via config file.

In EE Control Panel...

[image]

As Folders...

[image]

Even more straightforward in EE3...

[image]

Or if you want sub-folders in sub-folders, then you'll have to opt for a third-party add-on like [Assets](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/assets) (EE2 only).

Comment: Thanks for the message @peter 

I think I'm looking for something like Assets, unfortunately it's not EE3 ready..